# add text to header of jquery UI tab control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I would like to add some text to the header of a jquery UI tab control (see image). It would be good if I could align it on the right side.

[image]

Comment: It's a fair question, in my opinion.  I'm guessing you'd have to add it as a tab, but then style that tab differently (and disable it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this

```
$("#id_of_tab_element").tabs(); //init of your tabs element
var textElement = $("<span></span>");
textElement.text("text here...");
```

apply styles and append

```
textElement.css('position', 'absolute');
textElement.css('right', '20px');
$("#id_of_tab_element").append(textElement);
```

you could also define the styles in css and apply a class to the element

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ufk32/) fiddle

Comment: okay, that is really easy. Pretty embarrassing I didn't think of that. Works! Thank you

Comment: I needed to add  textElement.css('top', '10px'); to get it to work.

Answer (score 5):

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
       <span style="float: right;">hello</span>
</ul>
```

Comment: while you can do this as I did (even though only `li` elements go inside of `ul` elements), it will not behave properly in IE7 and renders the `span` element (or `div` in my case) as part of the previous `li`.